# A whole basic game project Arduino

Tags: arduino-uno, programming, c++, arduino-ide

Firstly, I know that I have already posted this. I do not think anyone here is stupid so:
The game is: a power source connected to 6 buttons connected to 6 LEDs. you press them all in the randomly generated order, and they blink in the order pressed after completion, then randomize and reset.

I have an array shuffler code  1)Does the array shuffler work 2)How do I configure ports and attach them to values in the array, 3) How do I use an if-then statement to say if all buttons pressed in order, then LEDs blink 3 times?  I have a picture but not the actual Arduino, so, upon request, I can post the picture. Thank you. code:

```
void setup() {
    // put your setup code here, to run once:
}

void loop() {
    // put your main code here, to run repeatedly:
    int questionNumberArray[] = {0,1,2,3,4,5,6};//the array itself
    const size_t n = sizeof(questionNumberArray) / //the array used
    sizeof(questionNumberArray[0]);//the base of the array

    for (size_t i = 0; i < n - 1; i++) //the loop itself
    {
        size_t j = random(1, n - i);
        int t = questionNumberArray[i]; //integer output for increase
        questionNumberArray[i] = questionNumberArray[j];//the value definition
        questionNumberArray[j] = t;
    }

}
```

The six buttons are connected to digital pins (1, 2, 9, 11, 12, 13)

Comment: If you've already posted this, why have you posted it again? It won't get answered any quicker.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [array shuffler if-then and output question](http://arduino.stackexchange.com/questions/16965/array-shuffler-if-then-and-output-question)

Comment: Yes, this version is just much more organized so...I figured people would be more inclined to answer it

Comment: my arduino's ports are 1, 2, 9, 11, 12, and 13. for me to link to them at the top of the code how would I distinguish between all the different PinB's. also, they would be pins, not ports right, since there needs to be detection of the button being pressed?

Comment: What pins are the 6 buttons connected to?

Comment: @Chris ports 1, 2, 9, 11, 12, and 13

Comment: I assumed those were for the leds. What pins are the leds on then?

Comment: @Chris same. power connects to ports which connects to buttons which then connect to LEDs

Comment: The leds need to be connected to some pins in order for the arduino to turn them on and off. Can you upload a picture of the schematic you are using? You can download and make a schematic with a breadboard with fritzing. It's free here: http://fritzing.org/download/

Comment: `this version is just much more organized so` - you know you can edit your original question, right?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So you leds are connected to "pins" not "ports." Since each of the buttons will turn on only 1 led we need to keep track of which button pairs with which led. To do this we can use a `struct` like this one:

```
struct ButtonLed{   
        int buttonPin;
        int ledPin;
};
```

You declare a `ButtonLed` like this: `ButtonLed button1 = {1, 0}` where the first parameter is the button's pin and the second is the led's pin. **(All of the led pins are set to 0 since I don't know which pins you have them connected to.)**

And the array will hold the button/led pin pair like this:

`ButtonLed questionNumberArray[] = {button1, button2, button3, button4, button5, button6};`

Since there are 6 leds you know that your array is size 6 so use this declaration instead

`const int n = 6;`

I fixed you range for the random number generation. Look at the documentation for `random()` here https://www.arduino.cc/en/Reference/Random. We can use this function for shuffling the array.

```
void shuffleArray (ButtonLed arr [], const int size){
    for (int i = 0; i < size - 1; i++){ // iterates through array except last element
        int j = random(0, size); // generates a random index from (0 to n-1) inclusive

        // swap current index with random index
        ButtonLed t = arr[i]; 
        arr[i] = arr[j];
        arr[j] = t;
    }
}
```

We will use this function to wait until the user enters a sequence of button presses:

```
ButtonLed getButtonPress (ButtonLed arr [], const int size){
    bool pressed = false;
    ButtonLed  pressedButton;
    while (!pressed){ // loops until a button was pressed
        for (int i = 0; i < size && !pressed; i++){ // !pressed allows early out
            if (digitalRead(arr[i].buttonPin)){ // one of the six buttons was pressed
                pressed = true; // exit both loops
                pressedButton = arr[i]; // stores which button was pressed
            }
        }
    }
    return pressedButton; // return the pressed button
}
```

Essentially it gets stuck in a loop and reads each of the 6 buttons until one of them is pressed and then records which one was pressed.

Try using the code below and read the comments the only thing you need to do is change all the zeros in the `ButtonLed` declarations to whatever pin the leds are connected to. Also the `struct` above needs to go into it's only file called "ButtonLed.h" It **must** be called that.

```
#include "ButtonLed.h"

// These are ButtonLeds our newly created data type
// they hold both an led's pin and the pin for the button
// that turns it on
ButtonLed button1 = {1, 10};
ButtonLed button2 = {2,  8};
ButtonLed button3 = {9,  7};
ButtonLed button4 = {11, 6};
ButtonLed button5 = {12, 5};
ButtonLed button6 = {13, 4};

// This function will randomly shuffle an array of ButtonLeds
void shuffleArray (ButtonLed arr [], const int size){
    for (int i = 0; i < size - 1; i++){ // iterates through array except last element
        int j = random(0, size); // generates a random index from (0 to size-1) inclusive

        // swap current index with random index
        ButtonLed t = arr[i]; 
        arr[i] = arr[j];
        arr[j] = t;
    }
}

ButtonLed getButtonPress (ButtonLed arr [], const int size){
    bool pressed = false;
    ButtonLed  pressedButton;
    while (!pressed){ // loops until a button was pressed
        for (int i = 0; i < size && !pressed; i++){ // !pressed allows early out
            if (digitalRead(arr[i].buttonPin)){ // one of the six buttons was pressed
                digitalWrite(digitalRead(arr[i].ledPin, HIGH); // turns on the led the user chose
                delay(200);
                digitalWrite(digitalRead(arr[i].ledPin, LOW); // turns it back off
                pressed = true; // exit both loops
                pressedButton = arr[i]; // stores which button was pressed
            }
        }
    }
    return pressedButton; // return the pressed button
}



void setup() {
    randomSeed(analogRead(A0));
    // This is how you set up the leds for output
    pinMode(button1.ledPin, OUTPUT);
    pinMode(button2.ledPin, OUTPUT);
    pinMode(button3.ledPin, OUTPUT);
    pinMode(button4.ledPin, OUTPUT);
    pinMode(button5.ledPin, OUTPUT);
    pinMode(button6.ledPin, OUTPUT);

    // This is how you set up the buttons for input
    pinMode(button1.buttonPin, INPUT);
    pinMode(button2.buttonPin, INPUT);
    pinMode(button3.buttonPin, INPUT);
    pinMode(button4.buttonPin, INPUT);
    pinMode(button5.buttonPin, INPUT);
    pinMode(button6.buttonPin, INPUT);
}

void loop() {

    // This array is of type ButtonLed our newly created data type
    ButtonLed questionNumberArray[] = {button1, button2, button3, 
                                       button4, button5, button6}; 
    const size_t n = 6; // array's size

    shuffleArray(questionNumberArray, n);


    numLeds = 1;
    bool guessCorrectly = false;

    // this while loop allows the user to keep trying until they get it right
    while (!guessCorrectly){


        // This loop displays the correct sequence to the user
        for (int i = 0; i < numLeds; i++){
            digitalWrite(questionNumberArray[i].ledPin, HIGH); // turn on the led

            delay(500); // decrease this number to flash faster; increase to flash slower

            digitalWrite(questionNumberArray[i].ledPin, LOW); // turn off the led
        }


        bool correctButton = true; // the user has pressed the correct button
        ButtonLed userSequence [6];      // stores the sequence the user entered
        // lets the user push 6 buttons
        for (int i = 0; i < numLeds; i++){
            userSequence[i] = getButtonPress(questionNumberArray, numLeds);
            delay(500); // delay between button presses
        }

        // check if the user entered the correct sequence
        for (int i = 0; i < numLeds && correctButton; i++){ 
            if (userSequence[i].buttonPin != questionNumberArray[i].buttonPin)
                correctButton = false;
        }

        if (correctButton){ // user entered the correct sequence
            guessCorrectly = true;
            // This will turn on the leds in the correct sequence
            for (int i = 0; i < numLeds; i++){
                digitalWrite(questionNumberArray[i].ledPin, HIGH); // turn on the led
                delay(500); // delay half a second
                digitalWrite(questionNumberArray[i].ledPin, LOW); // turn off the led
            }
            numLeds++;
            if (numLeds > 6)
                --numLeds;
        }
    }
}
```

After you are finished typing the code above it `ctrl+shift+n` and open a new tab called "ButtonLed.h" and add this to it:

```
#ifndef BUTTONLED_H
#define BUTTONLED_H
#include <Arduino.h>

// We create new data type called ButtonLed which stores the button's pin
    // and the led's pin; this allows us to keep both an led and it's
    // corresponding button together without have to manage 2 arrays
    struct ButtonLed{   
        int buttonPin;
        int ledPin;
    };

#endif
```

Make sure you open a new tab and not a new project. Also as others have said you should really learn how to program. Be aware this code compiles however, I haven't tested it. I will update the code when you tell me what pins the leds are connected to.

**Edit 1**

I added a while loop that allows the user to keep trying until they guess correctly.

**Edit 2**

I also updated the code for which pins the leds are connected to. Remember they're connected to "pins" **Not** "ports.

[image: Schematic for your project.]

Comment: The arduino looks like this: http://postimg.org/image/j65d4jd6b/59b97e93/

Comment: how do I choose an answer

Comment: how do i choose an answer, and what are the ports of the buttonLEDs in relation to the picture? They are hitting multiple points, how do I know which to use?

Comment: Ok so the way your arduino is set up right now won't work. This is because none of the leds are connected to the Arduino's pins. I have added a picture of a schematic to my answer. You must replicate the schematic exactly in order for it to work with the code. Also what do you mean by "choose an answer"? Do you mean "how do you guess a sequence?" or "how do you choose a sequence for someone else to guess?"

Comment: i mean literally the buttons are in place. to replace the zeros, which number do I put for each?

Comment: wait...where's the schematic?

Comment: Reload the page there's a picture at the end of the answer, also I've updated the code to replace the zeros. However, you have to connect the leds to the digital pins for it to work. You need to change the way your buttons are connected in order for them to work with the code. Did you want the leds to flash in order and then the user must remember that order?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/30461/discussion-between-chris-and-errr).